# What is the maximum length of a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I am wondering: Is the regular expression (itself) somehow limited?
I don't mean how I may shorten up a string length, but the regular expression itself.

Having a couple of hundreds values in an array I try to build up the regular expression from it (currently only this half is 600+ chars), but there is more to come.

So my regular expression would probably have a length of 1,000 or even more in the future.
Is it just limited by the PHP String length limit or is there something else in play?

Comment: Why would you even need a long regex? Optimal regexes matches dynamic expressions being short, and still work in excellence!

Comment: @Unihedron We could talk about this in chat, if you want. But I dont think this is relevant to this question.

Comment: Also if you intend for the size of the expression to scale, wouldn't that have performance consequences?

Comment: As I always say, "try not to use RegEx if you have other options available to you." for example, you can check a length of a string easily without using regEx. regEx are powerful indeed, but they are not always the best option

Comment: @Flosculus yes, I think it would. But also not really relevant to this question. I had a workaround but a coworker told me to do it this way. (Because my way was untested) - This way (the regex) is currently also not tested, but thats another story.

Comment: [There are some regexes longer than 6k character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245282/what-is-the-longest-regular-expression-you-have-seen), so I guess you are pretty much limited by the `string` object

Comment: @pquerner Since the answer to this question will essentially be a number, or a yes/no will work or not.  can you elaborate on the situation so we have a problem to solve? thanks.

Comment: @Ploutox thank you, I missed this question!

Comment: @Unihedron http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @Flosculus I can, but not in this topic. It seems that this one is closed by the "answer" provided by Ploutox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: As @Jonny 5 points out, my test was flawed. However, the correct answer is 32767, or if you see the second bit of my answer, 64k.

I've just tested it on my local machine using the following:

```
$str = str_repeat('a',  256*1024);
$subject = "";
$pattern = '/^' . $str . '/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

and I got:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 262145

In fact, you could have larger if you desired. Checking out the source, I tracked down [this](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/60846fab58eac05dc74584e90424de87c2992e08/ext/pcre/pcrelib/config.h#L227):

```
/* The value of LINK_SIZE determines the number of bytes used to store links
   as offsets within the compiled regex. The default is 2, which allows for
   compiled patterns up to 64K long. This covers the vast majority of cases.
   However, PCRE can also be compiled to use 3 or 4 bytes instead. This allows
   for longer patterns in extreme cases. On systems that support it,
   "configure" can be used to override this default. */
#ifndef LINK_SIZE
#define LINK_SIZE 2
#endif
```

so if you want to compile from source, knock yourself out.

Comment: Useful to know, +1.  Do you know if that is limited by the machine?

Comment: I have checked on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and it gives the same response for multiple versions tested. Perhaps there's a configurable option, perhaps not.

Comment: @Flosculus, if you're interested, see the second half of my answer I edited.

Comment: Removed my answer, was only to [show flaw](https://eval.in/179387) :)

Comment: Interesting read. Thank you for your answer. :)